# Как сделать движение колеса по заданным параметрам?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть сцена в Unity3D, где вводяться через `InputField` параметр скорости и времени. Дальше в скрипте вычисляется дистанция которую должно проехать данное колесо.

Как сделать так, чтобы это колесо ехало с заданной скоростью, заданное количество времени?

Нужно чтобы колесо не просто двигалось, а именно крутилось как в реальной жизни, то есть `Rigidbody` обязателен к использованию.

Comment: __AddForce()?    __

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все перечисленное включает в себя ровно то же самое что и в "реальной жизни".

1. Сам обьект колеса. Это цилиндр.
2. Обьект обладает физическими свойствами - добавлен `RigitBody`
3. Мы прикладаем усилие к колесу - задаем его скорость. Что бы скорость была стабильной - мы это делаем на каждом кадре. Скорость задается через `Velocity` или через `AddForce()`
4. Это нужно делать на каждом кадре пока не истечет необходимое время качения. Я бы советовал для этого использовать флаг `isInRiding`. То есть мы задаем скорость если этот флаг включен. Чтобы отключать флаг я бы советовал использовать библиотеку LeanTween. Там есть метод который может исполнять код через заданное время. В даном случае - переключить флаг.

И нужно так же учитывать что когда мы перестанем прикладывать усилие на каждом кадре - оно продолжит катится как и в реальной жизни. И будет катится еще некторое время пока скорость сама по себе не станет нулевой.